# Propagating errors between Hazelcast Server and Hazelcast Client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I have the following scenario:
- a Hazelcast Server as a microservice which performs some computations when receives a method call.
- a Hazelcast Client as another microservice which calls the Hazelcast Server through the specified method call.

I want that when I throw an exception from the Hazelcast Server to receive it on the Hazelcast Client side as it is (currently, I'm receiving somthing like this: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.client.UndefinedErrorCodeException: Class name: ro.orange.eshop.personalisationengineapi.application.exception.ValidationException`)

I've digged a little into the APIs and on the Hazelcast Client side I've found a way to register a new exception:

```
@Bean
    fun addHazelcastKnownExceptions(hazelcastInstance: HazelcastInstance): Int {
        val hazelcastClientInstance = (hazelcastInstance as HazelcastClientProxy).client
        hazelcastClientInstance.clientExceptionFactory.register(400, ValidationException::class.java) { message, cause -> ValidationException(message, cause) }
        return 1
    }
```

But it seems that this exception must be registered also on the server side as well. **And here comes the problem!** On the server side, I've found a class called `ClientExceptions` which has a method `public void register(int errorCode, Class clazz)` but I can't find a way to receive a `ClientExceptions` instance (I should mention that I'm using Hazelcast Spring).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported to register custom exception factory as an API as of 3.12.x. 
Related issue to follow https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/9753
As a workaround, I could suggest using class name (UndefinedErrorCodeException.getOriginialClassName()) to recreate exception classes on the client side.

**== EDIT ==**

Client API does not support it. You have found the private API. 
If you are ok with relying on private API here is the hack for registering classes on the hazelcast server:
Note that I DO NOT recommend this solution since it relies on private API that can change.

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
if (instance instanceof HazelcastInstanceProxy) {
   HazelcastInstanceImpl original = ((HazelcastInstanceProxy) instance).getOriginal();
   ClientExceptions clientExceptions = original.node.getClientEngine().getClientExceptions();
   clientExceptions.register( USER_EXCEPTIONS_RANGE_START + 1, UndefinedCustomFormatException.class);
}
```

Comment: I've already found that issue on github. I also know about the workaround, but if the Hazelcast Client API allows registering of custom exceptions, I think that it should be possible also on the server side.

Comment: I have edited my original answer with server side registration that relies on private  API.

Comment: @DinaBogdan were you able to figure out workaround for this on server side. I am not able to find this getClientExceptions method at all.